# Dovecot storing mails in /var/mail, but mail_location set to maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot

I have setup Mail Server Using Postfix, Dovecot and MySQL using this [link](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql).

**In Brief:**
My issue is I have made the postfix to handle off the mail delivery to dovecot as mentioned below. I have set the mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n in dovecot, but still mails getting delivered to /var/mail/

**/etc/postfix/main.cf :**

```
#Handing off local delivery to Dovecot's LMTP, and telling it where to store mail
#virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp 
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

**/etc/postfix/master.cf :**

```
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
   flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/local/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f
```

**/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf :**

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
```

**postconf -n (output):**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = mydomain.com
myhostname = mydomain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.1.0/24 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

**dovecot -n (output):**

```
# 2.2.22 (fe789d2): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.13 (7b14904)
# OS: Linux 4.4.0-36-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS ext4
auth_mechanisms = plain login
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = mail
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp
service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 0
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
```

**Below are the the complete files :**

**/etc/postfix/main.cf :**

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# SSL/TLS certificates
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes

# TLS parameters
#smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
#smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
#smtpd_use_tls=yes
#smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
#smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

#smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
#smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
#smtpd_use_tls=yes
#smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

#Enabling SMTP for authenticated users, and handing off authentication to Dovecot
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject_unauth_destination

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
#mydestination = mydomain.com, mail.mydomain.com
mydestination = mydomain.com
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.1.0/24 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

#Handing off local delivery to Dovecot's LMTP, and telling it where to store mail
#virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot

#Virtual domains, users, and aliases
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf,
        mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf
```

**/etc/postfix/master.cf :**

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/local/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

**/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf :**

```
user = mailuser
password = xxxxxxxxx
hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = mailserver
query = SELECT destination FROM virtual_aliases WHERE source='%s'
```

**/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf :**

```
user = mailuser
password = xxxxxxxxxxx
hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = mailserver
query = SELECT email FROM virtual_users WHERE email='%s'
```

**/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf :**

```
user = mailuser
password = xxxxxxxxxxxx
hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = mailserver
query = SELECT 1 FROM virtual_domains WHERE name='%s'
```

**/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf :**

```
user = mailuser
password = xxxxxxxxxx
hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = mailserver
query = SELECT 1 FROM virtual_users WHERE email='%s'
```

**/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf :**

```
## Dovecot configuration file

# If you're in a hurry, see http://wiki2.dovecot.org/QuickConfiguration

# "doveconf -n" command gives a clean output of the changed settings. Use it
# instead of copy&pasting files when posting to the Dovecot mailing list.

# '#' character and everything after it is treated as comments. Extra spaces
# and tabs are ignored. If you want to use either of these explicitly, put the
# value inside quotes, eg.: key = "# char and trailing whitespace  "

# Default values are shown for each setting, it's not required to uncomment
# those. These are exceptions to this though: No sections (e.g. namespace {})
# or plugin settings are added by default, they're listed only as examples.
# Paths are also just examples with the real defaults being based on configure
# options. The paths listed here are for configure --prefix=/usr
# --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var

# Enable installed protocols
!include_try /usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/*.protocol
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp

# A comma separated list of IPs or hosts where to listen in for connections. 
# "*" listens in all IPv4 interfaces, "::" listens in all IPv6 interfaces.
# If you want to specify non-default ports or anything more complex,
# edit conf.d/master.conf.
#listen = *, ::

# Base directory where to store runtime data.
#base_dir = /var/run/dovecot/

# Name of this instance. Used to prefix all Dovecot processes in ps output.
#instance_name = dovecot

# Greeting message for clients.
#login_greeting = Dovecot ready.

# Space separated list of trusted network ranges. Connections from these
# IPs are allowed to override their IP addresses and ports (for logging and
# for authentication checks). disable_plaintext_auth is also ignored for
# these networks. Typically you'd specify the IMAP proxy servers here.
#login_trusted_networks =

# Sepace separated list of login access check sockets (e.g. tcpwrap)
#login_access_sockets = 

# Show more verbose process titles (in ps). Currently shows user name and
# IP address. Useful for seeing who are actually using the IMAP processes
# (eg. shared mailboxes or if same uid is used for multiple accounts).
#verbose_proctitle = no

# Should all processes be killed when Dovecot master process shuts down.
# Setting this to "no" means that Dovecot can be upgraded without
# forcing existing client connections to close (although that could also be
# a problem if the upgrade is e.g. because of a security fix).
#shutdown_clients = yes

# If non-zero, run mail commands via this many connections to doveadm server,
# instead of running them directly in the same process.
#doveadm_worker_count = 0
# UNIX socket or host:port used for connecting to doveadm server
#doveadm_socket_path = doveadm-server

# Space separated list of environment variables that are preserved on Dovecot
# startup and passed down to all of its child processes. You can also give
# key=value pairs to always set specific settings.
#import_environment = TZ

##
## Dictionary server settings
##

# Dictionary can be used to store key=value lists. This is used by several
# plugins. The dictionary can be accessed either directly or though a
# dictionary server. The following dict block maps dictionary names to URIs
# when the server is used. These can then be referenced using URIs in format
# "proxy::<name>".

dict {
  #quota = mysql:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext
  #expire = sqlite:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext
}

# Most of the actual configuration gets included below. The filenames are
# first sorted by their ASCII value and parsed in that order. The 00-prefixes
# in filenames are intended to make it easier to understand the ordering.
!include conf.d/*.conf

# A config file can also tried to be included without giving an error if
# it's not found:
!include_try local.conf
```

**/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf (only uncommented lines):**

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = mail
```

**ls -ld /var/mail (output):**

```
drwxrwsr-x 3 vmail vmail 4096 Sep 16 17:54 /var/mail
```

**/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf (only uncommented lines):**

```
disable_plaintext_auth = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
!include auth-sql.conf.ext
```

**/etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-sql.conf.ext :**

```
# Authentication for SQL users. Included from 10-auth.conf.
#
# <doc/wiki/AuthDatabase.SQL.txt>

#passdb {
 # driver = sql

  # Path for SQL configuration file, see example-config/dovecot-#sql.conf.ext
#}

# "prefetch" user database means that the passdb already provided the
# needed information and there's no need to do a separate userdb lookup.
# <doc/wiki/UserDatabase.Prefetch.txt>
#userdb {
#  driver = prefetch
#}

#userdb {
 # driver = static
#}

# If you don't have any user-specific settings, you can avoid the user_query
# by using userdb static instead of userdb sql, for example:
# <doc/wiki/UserDatabase.Static.txt>
#userdb {
  #driver = static
  #args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/vmail/%u
#}


#changed as in https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql
passdb {
  driver = sql
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
}
userdb {
  driver = static
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
}
```

**/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext (only uncommented lines):**

```
driver = mysql
connect = host=127.0.0.1 dbname=mailserver user=mailuser password=Owningjesta2life
default_pass_scheme = SHA512-CRYPT
password_query = SELECT email as user, password FROM virtual_users WHERE email='%u';
```

**ls -ld /etc/dovecot (output)**

```
drwxr-x--- 4 vmail dovecot 4096 Sep 16 14:50 /etc/dovecot
```

**/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf :**

```
#default_process_limit = 100
#default_client_limit = 1000

# Default VSZ (virtual memory size) limit for service processes. This is mainly
# intended to catch and kill processes that leak memory before they eat up
# everything.
#default_vsz_limit = 256M

# Login user is internally used by login processes. This is the most untrusted
# user in Dovecot system. It shouldn't have access to anything at all.
#default_login_user = dovenull

# Internal user is used by unprivileged processes. It should be separate from
# login user, so that login processes can't disturb other processes.
#default_internal_user = dovecot

#changed as in https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql

#service imap-login {
#  inet_listener imap {
#    #port = 143
#  }
#  inet_listener imaps {
#    #port = 993
#    #ssl = yes
#  }

service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    #port = 0
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }

  # Number of connections to handle before starting a new process. Typically
  # the only useful values are 0 (unlimited) or 1. 1 is more secure, but 0
  # is faster. <doc/wiki/LoginProcess.txt>
  #service_count = 1

  # Number of processes to always keep waiting for more connections.
  #process_min_avail = 0

  # If you set service_count=0, you probably need to grow this.
  #vsz_limit = $default_vsz_limit
}

#changed as in https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql

#service pop3-login {
#  inet_listener pop3 {
#    #port = 110
#  }
#  inet_listener pop3s {
#    #port = 995
#    #ssl = yes
#  }
#}

service pop3-login {
    inet_listener pop3 {
      port = 0
    }
    inet_listener pop3s {
      port = 995
      ssl = yes
    }
}

#changed as in https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql

#service lmtp {
#  unix_listener lmtp {
    #mode = 0666
#  }

  # Create inet listener only if you can't use the above UNIX socket
  #inet_listener lmtp {
    # Avoid making LMTP visible for the entire internet
    #address =
    #port = 
  #}
#}

service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
   }
    # Create inet listener only if you can't use the above UNIX socket
    #inet_listener lmtp {
      # Avoid making LMTP visible for the entire internet
      #address =
      #port =
    #}
  }

service imap {
  # Most of the memory goes to mmap()ing files. You may need to increase this
  # limit if you have huge mailboxes.
  #vsz_limit = $default_vsz_limit

  # Max. number of IMAP processes (connections)
  #process_limit = 1024
}

service pop3 {
  # Max. number of POP3 processes (connections)
  #process_limit = 1024
}

#changed as in https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql

#service auth {
  # auth_socket_path points to this userdb socket by default. It's typically
  # used by dovecot-lda, doveadm, possibly imap process, etc. Users that have
  # full permissions to this socket are able to get a list of all usernames and
  # get the results of everyone's userdb lookups.
  #
  # The default 0666 mode allows anyone to connect to the socket, but the
  # userdb lookups will succeed only if the userdb returns an "uid" field that
  # matches the caller process's UID. Also if caller's uid or gid matches the
  # socket's uid or gid the lookup succeeds. Anything else causes a failure.
  #
  # To give the caller full permissions to lookup all users, set the mode to
  # something else than 0666 and Dovecot lets the kernel enforce the
  # permissions (e.g. 0777 allows everyone full permissions).
#  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    #mode = 0666
    #user = 
    #group = 
#  }

  # Postfix smtp-auth
#  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
#    mode = 0666
#    user = postfix
#    group = postfix
#  }

  # Auth process is run as this user.
  #user = $default_internal_user
#}


service auth {
  # auth_socket_path points to this userdb socket by default. It's typically
  # used by dovecot-lda, doveadm, possibly imap process, etc. Its default
  # permissions make it readable only by root, but you may need to relax these
  # permissions. Users that have access to this socket are able to get a list
  # of all usernames and get results of everyone's userdb lookups.
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }

  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
    #group =
  }

  # Postfix smtp-auth
  #unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
  #  mode = 0666
  #}

  # Auth process is run as this user.
  user = dovecot
}


#changed as in https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql

#service auth-worker {
  # Auth worker process is run as root by default, so that it can access
  # /etc/shadow. If this isn't necessary, the user should be changed to
  # $default_internal_user.
  #user = root
#}

service auth-worker {
  # Auth worker process is run as root by default, so that it can access
  # /etc/shadow. If this isn't necessary, the user should be changed to
  # $default_internal_user.
  user = vmail
}

service dict {
  # If dict proxy is used, mail processes should have access to its socket.
  # For example: mode=0660, group=vmail and global mail_access_groups=vmail
  unix_listener dict {
    #mode = 0600
    #user = 
    #group = 
  }
}
```

**/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf :**

```
##
## SSL settings
##


#Added for ssl support reffered https://scaron.info/blog/debian-mail-postfix-dovecot.html
# SSL/TLS support: yes, no, required. <doc/wiki/SSL.txt>
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem

# PEM encoded X.509 SSL/TLS certificate and private key. They're opened before
# dropping root privileges, so keep the key file unreadable by anyone but
# root. Included doc/mkcert.sh can be used to easily generate self-signed
# certificate, just make sure to update the domains in dovecot-openssl.cnf
#ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
#ssl_key = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem

# If key file is password protected, give the password here. Alternatively
# give it when starting dovecot with -p parameter. Since this file is often
# world-readable, you may want to place this setting instead to a different
# root owned 0600 file by using ssl_key_password = <path.
#ssl_key_password =

# PEM encoded trusted certificate authority. Set this only if you intend to use
# ssl_verify_client_cert=yes. The file should contain the CA certificate(s)
# followed by the matching CRL(s). (e.g. ssl_ca = </etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem)
#ssl_ca = 

# Require that CRL check succeeds for client certificates.
#ssl_require_crl = yes

# Directory and/or file for trusted SSL CA certificates. These are used only
# when Dovecot needs to act as an SSL client (e.g. imapc backend). The
# directory is usually /etc/ssl/certs in Debian-based systems and the file is
# /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem in RedHat-based systems.
#ssl_client_ca_dir =
#ssl_client_ca_file =

# Request client to send a certificate. If you also want to require it, set
# auth_ssl_require_client_cert=yes in auth section.
#ssl_verify_client_cert = no

# Which field from certificate to use for username. commonName and
# x500UniqueIdentifier are the usual choices. You'll also need to set
# auth_ssl_username_from_cert=yes.
#ssl_cert_username_field = commonName

# DH parameters length to use.
#ssl_dh_parameters_length = 1024

# SSL protocols to use
#ssl_protocols = !SSLv2

# SSL ciphers to use
#ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!LOW:!SSLv2:!EXP:!aNULL

# Prefer the server's order of ciphers over client's.
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = no

# SSL crypto device to use, for valid values run "openssl engine"
#ssl_crypto_device =

# SSL extra options. Currently supported options are:
#   no_compression - Disable compression.
#ssl_options =
```

I have been breaking my head on this for almost a month, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Would you add some log lines of a mail being delivered? All lines for a single mail being delivered through Postfix and Dovecot would be helpful.

Comment: @JensErat I am unable to add to the question as it is exceeding 3000 lines.

Comment: below is the log:  #update (log files for message being delivered):

  
    Sep 16 19:18:53 mydomain postfix/qmgr[13207]: 417F31941463: from=<rakshithskumar1988@gmail.com>, size=2486, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Sep 16 19:18:53 mydomain postfix/local[13399]: 417F31941463: to=<rakshithskumar@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.63, delays=0.59/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
    Sep 16 19:18:53 mydomain postfix/qmgr[13207]: 417F31941463: removed

Comment: And I can also see those messages in the webmin panel (Postfif configuration -> mailboxes) but not on any MUA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your log, the domain of the mail's recipient you are receiving is in mydestination. Mails that postfix receive which recipient's domain is in mydestination are delivered using local transport (as you can see in the log).

```
man 5 transport
```

Your mail is not sent to dovecot.

Many configurations are possible but the most straightforward:

mydomain.com is in the virtual domains table and mydestination do not contain mydomain.com (put localhost as in the tutorial you linked).

Comment: You made my day. Thanks a lot for the help. Can you please elaborate the answer. Its a request. I am curious as to why it does not send mails when mydestination is set to mydomain.com. I even have added mydomain.com in my /etc/hosts.

Comment: You're welcome.Postfix DOES **deliver** mails when mydestination contains mydomain.com but delivers it using **local** transport. It's just the way postfix divides it's default configuration. mydestination -> local_transport, virtual_mailbox_maps -> virtual_transport. I'm highly summarizing. transports are "things" declared in master.cf. You can for example "local_transport = $virtual_transport". I'm not even talking about relay and default transport and authorizations. Take your time to be curious about postconf(5), transport(5), master(5),etc,http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html.

Comment: Thanks once again for taking time to explain. I will visit the link and try to understand.